# C# how to wait for a webpage to finish loading

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to find a method of waiting a number of milliseconds before moving to the next line of code,

I have looked into Thread.Sleep but this will freeze the main form, I would like this to remain active

Comment: Which .Net version are you using please?

Comment: share your code so that we can understand.

Comment: @hadi saker The question is very broad and it's impossible to give a sensible answer without more context. Can you please share a snippet of your code and describe the behavior that you desire? P.S. you almost certainly need some kind of multithreading...

Answer (score 0):

Import this package below

**using System.Threading.Tasks;**

If you are using .Net framework 4.5 then can use Task.Delay

```
await Task.Delay(2000);
```

You dont have to use Thread.sleep.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this because you are working directly with a browser, threading will be a nightmare, if you have a browser control then this is what your actually looking for:

(wb is the browser control in this instance)

```
while(wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
     Application.DoEvents();
}
```

This is used when navigating to wait for the page to load, anything after this only starts once the page has progressed.
I would recommend spoofing the server requests so you dont have to worry about javascript etc but if the site is simple this will work.